# Eloquent model columns as properties

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, data-modeling

I am working with laravel and eloquent, I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, I've already made some search on google but couldn't find something like this.

I have a Company model which has a "hasMany" relationship with a CompanyProperties model. The CompanyProperties has two columns: "name" and "value".

```
id | Name           | Value
1  | primaryColor   | #000
2  | secondaryColor | #333
```

When I get the companies with Company::all(); it loads perfectly the CompanyProperties of each company. Every CompanyProperty returns a collection, which I can access using $company->CompanyProperties[0...n].

What I'd like to do if it's possible is that the CompanyProperties are accessible using the "name" column value as property or as an array. Using the example of my table above:
$company->CompanyProperties['primaryColor'] 
or
$company->CompanyProperties['secondaryColor']

Is there a way to do this?

**Oh yea, many thanks in advance.** I appreciate any advice you could have on this (even if I have to change the "properties" approach, haha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Laravel 5.1** and before: Use the `lists` method
**Laravel 5.2**: Use `pluck`

```php
$properties = $company->companyProperties()->pluck('Value', 'Name');
```

This returns an array where the value is the the 1st argument (`'Value'`) and the key is the 2nd argument (`'Name'`), e.g.

```php
$value = $properties['primaryColor']; // '#000'
```

However, this can be pretty inefficient because you're running a query for each company that you fetch. If it's just one or a few companies that's ok but given that you're using `Company:all()` I would recommend eager loading:

```php
$companies = Company::all();
$companies->load([
    'companyProperties'
]);
```

That will fetch the properties for all companies in a single query. Now for every $company, `$company->companyProperties` is a [Collection](http://laravel.com/docs/master/collections). So you can use the [keyBy](http://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-keyby) method:

```php
foreach ($companies as $company) {
    $properties = $company->companyProperties->keyBy('Name');

    $value = $properties['primaryColor']->Value; // '#000'
}
```

Notice that the syntax is slightly different, `$properties['primaryColor']` is still a companyProperties object, so you have to get the attribute `->Value`

Comment: And one last unrelated recommendation, I would just give the method name `properties`. You can still call the class `CompanyProperties`, or better yet namespace it to `App\Companies\Properties`. `$company->companyProperties` just feels redundant to me

Comment: Thank you. These advices are definitely helping me, the naming recommendation also is very enlightning, actually I felt that in fact and now I know  how to solve it. Thanks again.

Comment: @andrewtweber One little suggestion: you can combine the eager loading into one statement with just `$companies = Company::with('companyProperties')->get();`.

Comment: @patricus I know about that but I like to separate it out just so it's very clear. But thanks!